# Remove Duplicates and Sum Formula

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, sum, formula

I have a set of data that will change so I need a formula to dynamically get a result.

From this set of data I end up with two columns, Dates and Amounts, like the following:

[image: Current]

What I need is to be able to remove the duplicates from the Dates column, while summing the corresponding amounts. So each unique date will have its own row with an amount that is a sum of all the amounts with this date.
Desired Result:

[image: Result]

How would I go about this? Can I do it in a formula or do I need VBA?

Fairly new to excel, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is *exactly* what pivot tables do :)

Comment: [Learn Pivot Tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) You'll love it! :)

Comment: Pivot is the way to go, but if you must stay on the same sheet, you could add two columns, one for tally (=IF(H3=H2,J3+I2,I2)) and one for sequence (=IF(H1=H2,K1+1,1)), then filter on sequence of '1'  [H=date, I=amount]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Pivot Tables are my new friend.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to pivot tables in **C1** enter:

```
=MIN(A1:A100)
```

In **C2** enter the array formula:

```
=IF(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$100>C1,$A$1:$A$100))<C1,"",MIN(IF($A$1:$A$100>C1,$A$1:$A$100)))
```

and copy down.
Apply a *Date* format to column **C**.
Column **C** extracts the unique dates from column **A**.

In **D1** enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$A$100=C1)*($B$1:$B$100))
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.